# How to make silent print in WinUI3?

Tags: c#, winui-3

I need to print document (XAML page) via "Print to PDF" printer without preview stage. I'm using an [example](https://github.com/marb2000/PrintSample) of Windows.UI.Xaml.Printing. How can I immediately send a document to a specific printer (Microsoft Print to PDF) upon clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the PORT from:

`PORTPROMPT:` which asks for a file

I think this works in Windows 11 too, but the link is for Windows Server:

[How to Print to File without user intervention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/printing/print-to-file-without-user-intervention)

[image]

The steps from above link:

Here are the steps to achieve it:

1. Go to Devices and Printers.
2. Click on Add Printers.
3. Click on Add a local or network printer as an administrator.
4. Click on Add a local printer.
5. Click on Create a new port: Local Port.
6. You will get a Port Name Box - Type in Path and the file name. for example, "C:\Temp\PrintJob.txt".
7. Select the Manufacturer - Generic.
8. Select Printers - Generic / Text Only.
9. Select - Use the driver that is currently installed (recommended).
10. Type a name for the printer.
11. Share the Printer if needed.
12. Finish.

After these steps, any print jobs sent to this printer will automatically be saved to the location specified as the port.

Comment: @KJ Of course, you should only change the Port, to a file destination, and not the driver,   That is indeed unclear, I see If I can change the text to make it more clear, but do not have time to do it (correctly) now....